# Cannot get a data with Axios on ReactJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, axios

I am new developer **ReactJS**, I develop a table  with **ReactJS** on the FrontEnd, **NodeJS** on BackEnd and **MySQL** about the database.
I want to get a data with Select request on the table,
I test it on the backend with *Postaman*, it works well.

My front End :

```
class ListeClients extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      clients: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("inside componentWillMount");
    let self = this;
    axios({
      method: "get",
      url: "/app/listeclients/",
      withCredentials: true,
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json"
      }
    })
      .then(response => {
        // const clients = response.data;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
        self.clients = response.data;
        //    this.setState({clients});
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.clients);
    return (
      <div className="animated fadeIn">
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <Card>
              <CardHeader>
                <h4>
                  <strong>
                    <i className="fa fa-align-justify" /> Tous les clients
                  </strong>
                </h4>
              </CardHeader>
              <CardBody>
                <div className="container">
                  <div className="panel panel-default p50 uth-panel">
                    <table className="table table-hover">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Code</th>
                          <th>Prenom</th>
                          <th>Nom</th>
                          <th>Email</th>
                          <th>Telephone</th>
                          <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        {this.state.clients.map(client => (
                          <tr key={client.id}>
                            <td>{client.Code} </td>
                            <td>{client.Prenom}</td>
                            <td>{client.Nom}</td>
                            <td>{client.Email}</td>
                            <td>{client.Telephone}</td>
                            <td>
                              <a>Edit</a>|<a>Delete</a>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        ))}
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </CardBody>
            </Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ListeClients;
```

but when I run it on ReactJS, I get :

```
[]
length: 0__proto__: Array(0)concat: ƒ concat()constructor: ƒ Array()copyWithin: ƒ copyWithin()entries: ƒ entries()every: ƒ every()fill: ƒ fill()filter: ƒ filter()find: ƒ find()findIndex: ƒ findIndex()forEach: ƒ forEach()includes: ƒ includes()indexOf: ƒ indexOf()join: ƒ join()keys: ƒ keys()lastIndexOf: ƒ lastIndexOf()length: 0map: ƒ map()pop: ƒ pop()push: ƒ push()reduce: ƒ reduce()reduceRight: ƒ reduceRight()reverse: ƒ reverse()shift: ƒ shift()slice: ƒ slice()some: ƒ some()sort: ƒ sort()splice: ƒ splice()toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()toString: ƒ toString()unshift: ƒ unshift()values: ƒ values()Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ values()Symbol(Symbol.unscopables): {copyWithin: true, entries: true, fill: true, find: true, findIndex: true, …}__proto__: Object
ListeClients.js:15 inside componentWillMount
```

I want to get data on this table :

[image]

How to fix that please ?

Comment: Where you say `self.clients = response.data`, you are mutating the state. This should be changed to `self.setState({ clients: response.data })`. Although, I'm not sure why you declared `self` in the first place. It's pretty obvious in ES6 what `this` refers to.

Comment: @NorianNyx  I try that, but it's still the same issue.

Comment: What do you see in the server log when you make the request from client?

Comment: @ArupRakshit  I get the result of Select query on my server log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your component should be like this:

```js
class ListeClients extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      clients: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios({
      method: "get",
      url: "/app/listeclients/",
      withCredentials: true,
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json"
      }
    })
      .then(response => {
        if (response && response.data) {
          this.setState({ clients: response.data });
        }
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

  render() {
    let { clients } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="animated fadeIn">
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <Card>
              <CardHeader>
                <h4>
                  <strong>
                    <i className="fa fa-align-justify" /> Tous les clients
                  </strong>
                </h4>
              </CardHeader>
              <CardBody>
                <div className="container">
                  <div className="panel panel-default p50 uth-panel">
                    <table className="table table-hover">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Code</th>
                          <th>Prenom</th>
                          <th>Nom</th>
                          <th>Email</th>
                          <th>Telephone</th>
                          <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        {clients &&
                          clients.length &&
                          clients.map(client => (
                            <tr key={client.id}>
                              <td>{client.Code} </td>
                              <td>{client.Prenom}</td>
                              <td>{client.Nom}</td>
                              <td>{client.Email}</td>
                              <td>{client.Telephone}</td>
                              <td>
                                <a>Edit</a>|<a>Delete</a>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          ))}
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </CardBody>
            </Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ListeClients;
```

1. You really don't have to declare `self = this`. Makes no sense.
2. You are mutating/changing the state properties directly, instead of using `this.setState` method provided by React.
3. You should Neeeever mutate the state directly unless its the `constructor`.

Comment: Thank you @Ajay , when I remove `clients && clients.length &&` , it works well

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the full URL:

```
axios({
  method: "get",
  url: "http:/[YOUR_SERVER_LOCATION]/app/listeclients/",
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Accept: "application/json"
  }
})
```

I think because this you are receiving a empty result.

Comment: I get : `Failed to load http://localhost:4000/app/listeclients/: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute. ListeClients.js:37 Error: Network Error at createError (createError.js:16) at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)`

Comment: This is a CORS issue. If you are using Node, which I think you are, then you can get around this by using this package: https://github.com/expressjs/cors

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the default axios get() method:

```
axios.get("/app/listeclients/")
  .then(response => {
    // const clients = response.data;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    self.clients = response.data;
    //    this.setState({clients});
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

It should work with json data well by default.

Comment: I get : `Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): Text nodes cannot appear as a child of <tbody>. in tbody (at ListeClients.js:61) in table (at ListeClients.js:50) in div (at ListeClients.js:49) in div (at ListeClients.js:48) in div (created by CardBody) in CardBody (at ListeClients.js:47) in div (created by Card) in Card (at ListeClients.js:39) in div (created by Col) in Col (at ListeClients.js:38) in div (created by Row) in Row (at ListeClients.js:37) in div (at ListeClients.js:36)`